# Limit the number of pages displayed in bootstrap navigation

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, pagination

I am using the below code to display the no of pages, but it is showing all the pages which I want to limit to display pages from 1 to 10 only with 100 results per page.

If you then select page 2, page 11 would b displayed and so on.

any help will be appreciated.

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
          <ul class="pagination">
            <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?start=1&end=100">Start</a></li>
           
          
            <?php 
            $t=$a;
            $k=2;
            
            while($t>0){
                ?>
                     <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?start=<?php echo ($k*100);?>&end=<?php echo ($k*100)+100;?>"><?php echo $k;?></a></li>
            
            <?php 
            $k++; 
            $t=$t-100;
            }?>
          
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?start=<?php echo $a-100;?>&end=<?php echo $a;?>">Last</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be best if you looped as you are doing but add some extra logic to the loop to check the iterations do not exceed 10 times what you are doing. You can then add some extra logic to show the start and last buttons and perhaps disable them when they are active.

Something like this ought to work but tweak it to suit your needs.

```
<ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item <?= ($current_page === 1) ? 'disabled' : ''; ?>">
    <a class="page-link" href="?page=1">Start</a>
</li>
<?php
    $page_limit = $current_page + 10;
    $i = $current_page + 1;
    while($i < $page_limit && $i < $num_of_pages) { ?>
        <li class="page-item">
            <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?=$i?>"><?=$i?></a>
        </li>
    <?php }
?>
<li class="page-item <?= ($current_page === $num_of_pages) ? 'disabled' : '' ?>">
    <a class="page-link" href="?page=<?= $num_of_pages ?>"><?= $num_of_pages ?></a>
</li>
```

I swapped out `start` and `end` with `page` and I'd recommend you do page size calculations where you process data rather than where you output data. It would be something like, you know page size is a 100 by default, then just take a page number and do the calculations when you are fetching data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: getting this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected single-quoted string "disabled", expecting "," or ";" in /tmp/4zf3v3gsl43pmxct/tester.php on line 14